# How can i Control VLC media player through a Python scripte

Tags: python, media-player, vlc

so I had this idea of controlling a media player from a python script like VLC for example, but since I am new to Python I don't know how to achieve that, 
so let me explain what I am looking for is
for example, I want to get and set a volume value of VLC from my Python script?
I am not asking for a whole code or something like that just some tips to follow and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's module vlc-ctrl for this automation. And then use subprocess module module to execute its commands.

1) Install vlc-ctrl through pip

```
pip install vlc-ctrl
```

test.py: (To volume up)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['vlc-ctrl',  'volume',  '+10%'])
```

And run code with:

```
python test.py
```

More documentation for vlc-ctrl module [here](https://pypi.org/project/vlc-ctrl/).

Comment: thank u so very much sir i will also take a look at the documentation for vlc-ctrl module,

Comment: one more question, what about the other video players?

Comment: For controlling other video players either you have to find its Python wrapper(If someone coded) from https://pypi.org or search for open source related projects on github. But the key is to look command line options provided by any media player. Because CLI of any media player can be handled using Python's subprocess module to issue command.

Answer (score 7):

Install python-vlc

```
pip install python-vlc
```

Just change the **path**,your good to go..

```
from vlc import Instance
import time
import os

class VLC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Player = Instance('--loop')

    def addPlaylist(self):
        self.mediaList = self.Player.media_list_new()
        path = r"C:\Users\dell5567\Desktop\engsong"
        songs = os.listdir(path)
        for s in songs:
            self.mediaList.add_media(self.Player.media_new(os.path.join(path,s)))
        self.listPlayer = self.Player.media_list_player_new()
        self.listPlayer.set_media_list(self.mediaList)
    def play(self):
        self.listPlayer.play()
    def next(self):
        self.listPlayer.next()
    def pause(self):
        self.listPlayer.pause()
    def previous(self):
        self.listPlayer.previous()
    def stop(self):
        self.listPlayer.stop()
```

Create a object

```
player = VLC()
```

Add playlist

```
player.addPlaylist()
```

Play the song

```
player.play()
time.sleep(9)
```

Play the next song

```
player.next()
time.sleep(9)
```

Pause the song

```
player.pause()
time.sleep(9)
```

Resume the song

```
player.play()
time.sleep(9)
```

Previous song

```
player.previous()
time.sleep(9)
```

Stop the song

```
player.stop()
```

Comment: Hi! What is the significance of using `sleep()`? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing special it's just let you know the difference of each command.

Answer (score 3):

Controlling vlc from tcp socket connection is better than vlc-ctrl. I tried vlc-ctrl in my raspberry pi,i cannot reach my expectation. So i decided to control the vlc player from socket connection.

Steps:-

1) you need to run from command prompt or from shell `'vlc --intf rc --rc-host 127.0.0.1:44500'`[starting vlc player] to enable vlc player for controlling it from tcp connection.... you can start vlc like this from python using subprocess.

2) for cntrolling from python here is my sample script:

```
class player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_initiated = False
        self.SEEK_TIME = 20
        self.MAX_VOL = 512
        self.MIN_VOL = 0
        self.DEFAULT_VOL = 256
        self.VOL_STEP = 13
        self.current_vol = self.DEFAULT_VOL

    def toggle_play(self):
        if not self.is_initiated:
            self.is_initiated = True
            self.thrededreq("loop on")
            self.thrededreq("random on")
            self.thrededreq("add /home/pi/Desktop/Music")#adding the music folder
            print("Init Playing")
            return
        self.thrededreq("pause")
        print("Toggle play")


    def next(self):
        if not self.is_initiated:
            self.toggle_play()
            return
        self.thrededreq("next")
        print("Next")
        pass

    def prev(self):
        if not self.is_initiated:
            self.toggle_play()
            return
        self.thrededreq("prev")
        print("Previous")
        pass

    def volup(self):
        self.current_vol = self.current_vol + self.VOL_STEP
        self.thrededreq("volume " + str(self.current_vol))
        print("Volume up")
        pass

    def voldown(self):
        self.current_vol = self.current_vol - self.VOL_STEP
        self.thrededreq("volume " + str(self.current_vol))
        print("Volume Down")
        pass

    def seek(self, forward: bool):
        length = self._timeinfo("get_length")
        print(length)
        cur = self._timeinfo("get_time")
        print(cur)
        if (forward):
            seekable = cur + self.SEEK_TIME
        else:
            seekable = cur - self.SEEK_TIME
        if seekable > length:
            seekable = length - 5
        if seekable < 0:
            seekable = 0
        self.thrededreq("seek " + str(seekable))
        print("Seek: ",seekable," Cur: ",cur,"Len: ",length)
        pass

    def _timeinfo(self, msg):
        length = self.req(msg, True).split("\r\n")
        if (len(length) < 2):
            return None
        length = length[1].split(" ")
        if (len(length) < 2):
            return None
        try:
            num = int(length[1])
            return num
        except:
            return None

    def req(self, msg: str, full=False):
        try:
            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
                # Connect to server and send data
                sock.settimeout(0.7)
                sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 44500))
                response = ""
                received = ""
                sock.sendall(bytes(msg + '\n', "utf-8"))
                # if True:
                try:
                    while (True):
                        received = (sock.recv(1024)).decode()
                        response = response + received
                        if full:
                            b = response.count("\r\n")
                            if response.count("\r\n") > 1:
                                sock.close()
                                break
                        else:
                            if response.count("\r\n") > 0:
                                sock.close()
                                break
                except:
                    response = response + received
                    pass
                sock.close()
                return response
        except:
            return None
            pass

    def thrededreq(self, msg):
        Thread(target=self.req, args=(msg,)).start()

#'vlc --intf rc --rc-host 127.0.0.1:44500' you need to run the vlc player from command line to allo controlling it via TCP
Player=player()
player.toggle_play()
#player.next()
#player.prev()
```

if you want more command and controlling,use"SocketTest" and connect to the port of vlc and check out....

this one has more control option than vlc-ctrl.

Comment: Ok, got it working. 1) added missing `import socket`. 2) added `import time` and used time.sleep(secs) at the end of the code, in between actions, since the code creates a new socket for every message sent. Maybe windows cant handle creating sockets too fast? I would have edited the code but SO says edit queue is full. Last thing, in Windows the path for the media/music needs to be escaped, ie `d:\\folder\\sub`.